# Form button that populates textbox is not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html

My button OnClick event uses Javascript to populate two wide textboxes with the selected options from multiple select boxes.

Everything works perfect in Firefox and Chrome but nothing happens when you click the button in Internet Explorer. I would appreciate any help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script type="text/javascript">

function addbutton1() {

var box1 = document.getElementById('dropdown1').options[document.getElementById('dropdown1').selectedIndex].text;
var box2 = document.getElementById('dropdown2').options[document.getElementById('dropdown2').selectedIndex].text;
var box3 = document.getElementById('dropdown3').options[document.getElementById('dropdown3').selectedIndex].text;
var box4 = document.getElementById('dropdown4').options[document.getElementById('dropdown4').selectedIndex].text;
var box5 = document.getElementById('dropdown5').options[document.getElementById('dropdown5').selectedIndex].text;
var box6 = document.getElementById('dropdown6').options[document.getElementById('dropdown6').selectedIndex].text;

textbox1.value = box1 + ',  ' + box2 + ',  ' + box3 + ',  ' + box4;
textbox2.value = box5 + ',  ' + box6;
}
</script>

<body>
<form name="customform" id="wstForm_Custom" action="%wstx.formmailerurl%" method="post" labelID="formLabel_CustomForm">
<style>
#wstForm_Custom {background-color:transparent;} .specialEmailField {display: none;visibility:hidden;height:0px;} .emailDisplay {display: none;visibility:hidden;height:0px;}
</style>

<table>

  <tr><td style="font-family:Arial; text-align: left; font-size: 10pt;">Row 1:</td>

  <td><select style="width: 150px" id="dropdown1">
  <option value='0'>Select</option>
  <option value='100.00'>Option 1a</option>
  <option value='100.00'>Option 1b</option>
  </select></td>

  <td><select style="width: 150px" id="dropdown2">
  <option>Select</option>
  <option>Option 2a</option>
  <option>Option 2b</option>
  </select></td></tr>

  <tr><td style="font-family:Arial; text-align: left; font-size: 10pt;">Row 2:</td>

  <td><select style="width: 150px" id="dropdown3">
  <option>Select</option>
  <option>option 3a</option>
  <option>Option 3b</option>
  </select></td>

  <td><select style="width: 150px" id="dropdown4">
  <option>Select</option>
  <option>Option 4a</option>
  <option>Option 4b</option>
  </select></td>

  <tr><td style="font-family:Arial; text-align: left; font-size: 10pt;">Row 3:</td>

  <td><select style="width: 150px" id="dropdown5">
  <option value='0'>Select</option>
  <option value='0'>Option 5a</option>
  <option value='0'>Option 5b</option>
  </select></td></tr>

  <tr><td style="font-family:Arial; text-align: left; font-size: 10pt;">Row 4:</td>

  <td><select style="width: 150px" id="dropdown6">
  <option value='0'>Select</option>
  <option value='100.00'>Option 6a</option>
  <option value='100.00'>Option 6b</option>
  </select></td>

</table>

<button type="button" onclick="addbutton1(this.form)">Add Options to Textboxes</button>

<table style="width: 700px">
<tr>
<input style="width:480px" name="First Textbox" id="textbox1" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE="OFF"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<input style="width:480px" name="Second Textbox" id="textbox2" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE="OFF"/></td>
</tr>
</table>

<p style="width: 740px; text-align: center">

<input style="width:100px;" title="Submit" id="wstForm_Custom_Submit" onclick="return wstxSubmitForm(this);" type="submit" value="Submit"/> 

<input style="width:50px;" title="Reset Form" id="wstForm_Custom_Reset" type="reset" value="Reset"/>

</p>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `document.getElementById('textbox1').value` not simple `textbox1.value`.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/WbTmf/1/